# How can I insert multiple values from a range into MySQL columns?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database where I need add multiple values, but I need to specify a range of values just in one column.

I'm not an expert but the logic for what I need is this:

```
INSERT INTO ps_category_product (id_category, id_product, position) VALUES (56,BETWEEN 3 AND 5,0);
```

I know that is not possible to use BETWEEN in a insert into query, but how can I do something similar to specify the range of the id_product row?

How can I add all the values between 2 numbers like 3 and 5 (3,4,5) or 50 and 100 (50,51,52,...,98,99,100)

Comment: You want to insert a value of `id_product` that is between 3 and 5?

Comment: I want to insert the whole range of values between 2 numbers. e.g.:

between 3 and 5 (3,4,5) or 50 and 100 (50,51,52,...,98,99,100)

Comment: the `mt_rand` function will generate numbers between a range. e.g `mt_rand(3,5)` will give you `3,4,5`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table called range with two attributes representing the "range"... then you create a relationship(one to one) between "ps_category_product" and "new_table"...this way, in your ps_category_product table you will have a foreign key that references two values...

Comment: @Fernando Olvera, Did you try this solution?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use range of values while inserting. Rather, you will have to validate your insert values using a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` something like below (a sample)

```
CREATE TRIGGER validaterangeTrigger 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON ps_category_product
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.id_product NOT BETWEEN 3 AND 5) THEN
      SET NEW.id_product = 3; <-- setting a default value 3
    END IF
```

Then you can call your `INSERT` statement

```
INSERT INTO ps_category_product (id_category, id_product, position) VALUES (56,4,0);
```

If the `id_product` value is not between 3 and 5 then trigger will set it to default value 3. You can as well choose to throw an error if validation fails.

Comment: I tried doing this but I realized that just one value has been added instead of the whole range, how can I add all the values between 2 numbers like 3 and 5 (3,4,5) or 50 and 100 (50,51,52,...,98,99,100)

Comment: @FernandoOlvera, NO, you can't do that and moreover you shouldn't do that. Storing `,` separated values is against normalization concept. You will face issue later on when you try to join with other table.

Comment: The , separated values was just and example, I meant with (3,4,5) the whole range of numbers, I'm not going to write the SQL query as that, so should be understood as the range of the numbers not as the syntax. The same with 50 and 100 what I want to do is add a new row where just the id_product change the value with 50 or 51 or 52, etc., but the other values like id_category and position stay the same.